# how to call a function when user clears the browser cache

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, caching, browser-cache

I have created an application in AngularJS, The application is working fine also in my application I have used session management similar to what that is used in

http://plnkr.co/edit/Mvrte4?p=info

```
//set the browser session, to avoid relogin on refresh
$window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(loginData);
```

The session management is working fine but the problem is that say a user clears the cache and I want to trigger automatically a function even before the user clicks onto to any link, so the working is like the user clears the browser cache automatically login popup pops up immediately.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval and check if sessionStorage is not empty.

```
setInterval(function(){
   if (typeof $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] == 'undefined'){
     console.log("SHOW POPUP");
   }
},100);
```

Comment: but this will be running in seconds continuously ......... Actually I want to trigger a function only when the user clears the browser cache....can we do by using $watch on browser cache anything like that

Comment: I'd be really surprised if a user clearing their cache would trigger a $watch.

Comment: i think you can't add wachers on clean cache event :S

Comment: its just a guess.....dont know whether its doable, if not is there any other ways we can detect when user clears the cache( without using any setItervals )

Comment: Create a service that will intercept every ng-click you have and will check the storage size each time a user clicks something? ``ng-click="checkCookies(url)`` perhaps?

Comment: Get a handler at all and check when user click?